# Random text corruption on one monitor of two

Tags: windows, graphics-card

I've noticed that one of my two monitors randomly has messed up/garbled text in windows 10. A few reboots fixes it and sometimes it works fine. Text looks fine in the UEFI menus and preboot sceens and *video* appears fine. Apparently screenshots of the garbled screen look fine.

[image]

Bad

[image]

Good

This is the *same* monitor (also these are photographs - I actually *should* have screenshotted them but didn't think of it, oops)

I'm running a [zotac 980TI AMP!](https://www.zotac.com/us/product/graphics_card/gtx-980-ti-amp) - a crossover 289K (which has this issue) and a dell P2715Q which does not. Both monitors are connected over displayport

I've also found that this happened on a different monitor, on my built in intel video adaptor as well, over HDMI so I can rule out the video card.

The new monitor is a [a XPpen Artist Display 10S](https://www.xp-pen.com/product/56.html) connected over HDMI.

The only similarity between the monitors is, well they're somewhat cheap.

I've had this issue since I upgraded to a new PC (a core i9 9900K on a [asus z390-f](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-Z390-F-GAMING/)) I used the same video card on my older PC running a core i7 3770 with a p8-z77V. I've tried swapping ports on either end.

I don't know what version of the gforce drivers the old system was using but I currently run 419.35 .

Workarounds so far have been rebooting till things work correctly, unplugging and replugging the DP cable until things work correctly... but its painfully random. I recently found that unplugging the monitor and plugging it back in, then making video detect the video card seems to work.

I can rule out cleartype (the tuner does nothing).

Is there anything I can do to get this monitor working consistently?

I've added a third monitor since - and noticed the same issue with the monitor and not the others.

I can *probably* rule out the specific output(this was plugged in over HDMI). Its *plausible*, its always the 'last' monitor. I've also ruled out it being a specific display out or display adaptor since I just had the issue happen on the intel adaptor I use for the third monitor.

Comment: Does the issue persist if you switch the DisplayPort connections so that your Crossover and Dell displays swap outputs?  How about if you move the bad display's cable to the third DisplayPort port that is not in use?

Comment: Tried both actually

Comment: ClearType might be having problems.  Settings->Personalization->Fonts->Adjust ClearType Text ... try turning it off.  You might have to reboot to see a difference.

Comment: Well, the problem randomly resolves (and comes back) on a reboot so I'm not sure if I'd know if its due to cleartype turning off or its just magically working again.

Comment: Comparing the photos to screenshots might be useful, actually, if you get chance to grab both. Would at least check if it was 'transmission' or 'reception', card or screen.

Comment: Yup! I'll do that the next time it happens. That's the frustrating part. Its so random.

Comment: Screenshots look clean. I'm now... somewhat more baffled.

Comment: @J - That would say hardware to me - screen or cable; potentially GPU output. Gives you somewhere to start, I'd say.

Comment: I've ruled out the GPU (swapped GPUs), monitor (happens with different monitors, one of which I tested on both GPUs)...  and specific resolutions. Colour me confused.

Comment: A long time ago ('03-'04) I saw a similar effect when I underclocked my graphics card RAM too much.